# Java Doesnt realize if and else

Tags: java, if-statement

it doesn't realize that there is an if statement when i type a consonant.
and also when i type e, it realizes that its a consonant.

Also when i enter "a" it produces the if statment for string vowel and the else statement.
same with captial letter "A" but this time it produces the else twice.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class R
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        String[] vowels = {"a","e","i","o","u"};
        String[] vowel = {"A","E","I","O","U"};
        String InputVowel = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter a Character: ");
        for (int x=0;x<vowels.length;x++)
        {
            if(InputVowel.equals (vowels[x]))
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,InputVowel+" is a lowercase");
            if(InputVowel.equals(vowel[x]))
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,InputVowel+" is an uppercase");
            else
                x = 5;
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,InputVowel+" is a consaunant");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: so what i gather is java doesn't know there is an if statement? are you sure your logic is correct?

Comment: You should get into the habit of always using curly braces, even for one-line blocks. That `else` won't do what you want because you didn't add them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only assume it is not a vowel after checking all candidates (all vowels)

```
    String[] vowels = {"a","e","i","o","u"};
    String[] vowel = {"A","E","I","O","U"};
    String InputVowel = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter a Character: ");
    boolean isVowel = false;

    for (int x=0;x<vowels.length;x++)
    {
        if(InputVowel.equals (vowels[x])) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,InputVowel+" is a lowercase");
            isVowel = true;
            break;
        }
        if(InputVowel.equals(vowel[x])) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,InputVowel+" is an uppercase");
            isVowel = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (!isVowel)
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,InputVowel+" is an consaunant");
```

Comment: Does it?  Enter a non-alpha character and see if it tells you that the input is not a letter.

Comment: @hfontanez well it works for now, all i wanted is for the letters to work. so all good

Comment: @hfontanez I have suggested an answer. Please look into it.

Comment: @DingoDile I have suggested an answer please look into it

Answer (score 4):

The reason it can't recognize your `if-statements` is braces are required if you have more than one `if-statement` check. If you have an `if-else`, braces are required.

```
String[] vowels = {"a","e","i","o","u"};
String[] vowel = {"A","E","I","O","U"};
String InputVowel = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter a Character: ");

for (int x=0;x<vowels.length;x++) {
    if(InputVowel.equals (vowels[x])) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,InputVowel+" is a lowercase");
    } else if(InputVowel.equals(vowel[x])) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,InputVowel+" is an uppercase");
    } else {
        x = 5;
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,InputVowel+" is an consaunant");
    }
}
```

The above code should work.

Comment: @ikegami Ahh didn't notice that. Nice catch. :)

Comment: This code doesn't work. It doesn't say that e is a lowercase character

Comment: @subhamsoni Because this code is bad. It "breaks" if the first entry of `vowels` and `vowel` do not match `InputVowel` instead of checking the other entries.

Comment: @DingoDile, That's because there is more than one problem, and Drew only fixed one.

Comment: @Tom ya I know the logic is very very poor. Shall I post an answer for the improvised logic?

Comment: @subhamsoni Don't ask me :D. If you want to do that, then do it :).

Comment: @subhamsoni Go for it! I agree the logic provided is poor.

Comment: This code is very brittle. For example, if the character entered is '@', it will output "is a consonant" when in fact it isn't. Second, only ONE array of vowels is needed.  In psedocode: IF CHAR equals (ignore case) VOWEL[i] input IS VOWEL, ELSE IF CHAR is WITHIN alpha character values (41h - 5Ah OR 61h - 7Ah) IS consonant, ELSE is something else.

Answer (score 0):

Although the OP has already accepted an answer. This is an enhanced version of the program utilizing various features of the program.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class R
{
public static void main(String args[]){
String[] vowels = {"a","e","i","o","u"};
String InputVowel = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter a Character: ").trim();
String x = Integer.toHexString(InputVowel.charAt(0));
for(int i=0;i<vowels.length;i++)
{
    if(vowels[i].equalsIgnoreCase(InputVowel))
    {
        if(!(InputVowel.equals(vowels[i].toUpperCase())))
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,InputVowel+" is a vowel and lowercase character");
        else
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,InputVowel+" is a vowel and uppercase character"); 
        break;
    }


    else if(InputVowel.length()>1||(Integer.valueOf(x)>=0 && Integer.valueOf(x)<=40))
    {JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,InputVowel+" is not a valid character");break;}
    else
    {
        if(!InputVowel.equals(vowels[i].toUpperCase()))
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,InputVowel+" is a consonant and lowercase character");
        else
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,InputVowel+" is a consonant and uppercase character"); 
        break;
    }  
}
}
}
```

### Note

The input other than letters are handled (numbers and special characters) and for simplicity are labelled as non valid characters.

Comment: The `else-if` block does not need to be inside the `for` loop. Looping is only needed to determine if the input letter is a vowel. Also, you can't do the range like you did because between decimal values 65 and 122 there are characters that are not letters. The values for alpha characters are 65-90 AND 97-122 (inclusive).

Comment: @hfontanez if I am not wrong the range is only for ascii. But Java follows Unicode right? So I have used the range for Unicode for numbers and special characters

Comment: the character value is still the same for ASCII and Unicode Basic Latin character sets.